# Paypal API and several emails in same PayPal account

Tags: api, email, paypal, receiver

I can not praise with my contribution here, because I am new user, 
but would help if I can.

I have a big problem and I do not know how to solve it, please help.

In the same Paypal account with the default email address: email1@somedomain.com, there is 7 more emails:

```
email2@somedomain.com
email3@somedomain.com
email4@somedomain.com
email5@somedomain.com
email6@somedomain.com
email7@somedomain.com
```

that's the maximum allowed number of emails under one PayPal account (8).

So we are using API on several pages, and only one API signature can be done in the paypal
interface, so same API signature is used for each web page.

We would like to define where will money go - to which email address inside the same PayPal account.

We use Premium PayPal account, and we know that for logo change, email remove and so on, we would need Business account, 
but for defining money receiver email address inside the same PayPal account
we suppose that it can be defined, otherwise we do not se a point of having several email addresses inside one same PayPal account.

The problem is that always is shown default email when making a purchase :S
We tried to define SUBJECT:

```
SUBJECT=merchantEmailAddress
N O T  E: Typically, a merchant grants third-party permissions to a shopping cart...
```

And set merchantEmailAddress email2@somedomain.com.

In sandbox it works like a charm as soon as we put it on production, default mail is shown again.

Please if anyone had the same issue help.

Thank you very much, this forum is great and I realise that without nice people and contribution as well there would be no answers.

regards

Answer (score 0):

You would not be using SUBJECT unless dealing with Permissions and making calls on behalf of 3rd party PayPal accounts.

You're working with a single PayPal account, so you won't be using SUBJECT at all.  You'll use the credentials like you are already.

That said, I'm not sure I'm following you entirely what trying to send to different emails.  I don't understand the end goal with that..??  The API credentials are what are going to tell the system where to drop the money, or pull data from, or whatever.

If you're just trying to get different logos to show up during checkout you can do that with parameters in your standard button code or API requests.

Let me know if that helps or not.  Again, I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're after here.